# New and old passwords on same MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, password

Is it possible to set up a user in MySQL 5.5 with a new password whilst keeping existing users with the old type of passwords? By old and new passwords I mean the style of hash.

I was thinking I could try specify the hash directly but I'm struggling to get that working (I'm new MySQL).

Unfortunately I can't update all users to the new type of passwords as it would break access to a system I can't control. I also need the default new account to use the old style hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible before version 5.7, where it has been disabled.

To set up an old password for a user, use command:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'some_user'@'some_host' = OLD_PASSWORD('mypass');
```

More information: [Password Hashing in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/password-hashing.html).

You can enable/disable old passwords globally or per session. On a server where they are enabled globally (i.e. the server was started with `old_passwords = 1`), run this:

```
SET @@session.old_passwords = 0;
SET PASSWORD FOR 'test'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('mypass');
```

to disable them for a session. The PASSWORD in the above snippet will return a password in the new format, affecting only the current session.

Answer (score -1):

First you should stop or disable all the services if any other database is active on your system, then you can do it with an active instance of MySQL.